# Persist a list of LocalDate with GORM

Tags: grails, grails-orm, jodatime

I'm trying to persist a list of joda LocalDate in grails. What I have right now is something like this:

```
package com.publidirecta

import org.joda.time.LocalDate

class Evento {

    List <LocalDate> fechas = []

    static hasMany = [fechas:LocalDate]
}
```

and I get the following error :

```
MappingException: Missing type or column for column[fechas_persistent_local_date] on domain[Evento] referencing[org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate]
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

I tried with out the hasMany property, but doesnt work either(just didnt add anything)

Answer (score 1):

As Alidad suggested you should wrap the LocalDate with a new entity and have a on-to-many relationship with this entity. 
In addition you will have to take care of mapping the `LocalDate` type to the database since this is not a type natively supported by Hibernate. Take a look at this [guide](http://gpc.github.com/grails-joda-time/guide/persistence.html) which covers the topic.

Using the [User Type](http://usertype.sourceforge.net/usertype.jodatime/index.html) library your class should look something like:

```
package com.publidirecta

class Evento {

    static hasMany = [fechas: Fecha]

    List <Fecha> fechas = []
}
```

And

```
import org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate
import org.joda.time.LocalDate

class Fecha {
    LocalDate date

    static mapping = {
        date type: PersistentLocalDate
    }
}
```

Make sure your add the following to your `BuildConfig`:

```
dependencies {
        compile 'org.jadira.usertype:usertype.jodatime:1.9'
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your quick answer. I tried your solution but nothing happened. The error is gone, but the LocalDate dont persist on the data bases

Comment: I fixed my answer. Got used to thinking the MongoDB way instead of the relational database way.

Answer (score 0):

How about defining your 'fechas' as another domain with localDate and create hasmany relationship:

something like this:

/Evento.groovy

```
class Evento  {
 static hasMany = [fechas: Fecha]
}
```

/Fecha.groovy

```
import org.joda.time.LocalDate

class Fecha  {

    LocalDate date

}
```

Comment: That was my second option, but i found it just too messy, adding an additional domain class with just  one property