# Hibernate operation exception

Tags: hibernate, grails, jodatime

I am running a grails project. Maybe the question is for a beginner, but still help is important.

I have a domain object, Order. In the order class model I have declared the dateCreated as DateTime type using Joda-Time.

I am using:'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.2'

However the moment when the order.save() is called I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Hibernate operation: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; Data truncation: Data too long for column 'date_created' at row 1; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'date_created' at row 1
```

can you give me a hint what is going on?

Comment: what is the column type applied in the MySQL database for 'date_created'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this [solution](http://adhockery.blogspot.com/2010/06/defaulting-joda-time-hibernate-types.html):

in Domain Class:

```
import org.joda.time.*
import org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.*

DateTime dateCreated
DateTime lastUpdated
LocalDate birthday

static mapping = {
    dateCreated type: PersistentDateTime
    lastUpdated type: PersistentDateTime
    birthday type: PersistentLocalDate
}
```

in Config.groovy:

```
grails.gorm.default.mapping = {
    "user-type" type: PersistentDateTime, class: DateTime
    "user-type" type: PersistentLocalDate, class: LocalDate
}
```

or [another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506449/persist-a-list-of-localdate-with-gorm).

Comment: the second solution solved my problem. Thank you very much. You can discard my previous comment. :)